# use secureTextEntry, keyboard flashing on iOS13

Tags: ios, keyboard, uitextfield, ios13, quicktype

I have two UITextField.

```
phoneTextField.secureTextEntry = NO;
pwdTextField.secureTextEntry = YES;
```

after pwdTextField becomeFirstResponder, I click phoneTextField and input text, quicktype bar 
will flashing.The red box area will quick switch to hide and show.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q5xJI.jpg)

I try to use textContentType but it dosen't work.

how can I solve the problem, please help me! o(╥﹏╥)o

it would be batter that show quikType bar on pwdTF and hide on phoneTF. Or hide quikType bar and pwdTextField use secureText

Comment: What you want to achieve? Do you need to show quiktype bar on both or need to hide that?

Comment: t would be batter that show quikType bar on pwdTF and hide on phoneTF. Or hide quikType bar and pwdTextField use secureText @AshwiniSalunkhe

Comment: Are you using swift? At my end it is not showing the quicktype bar for both the textfield in swift with default keyboard.